# Get level by experience

Tags: php, optimization, levels, exp

I have this code:

```
 function getLevels($cEXP) {  // $cEXP is current player experience

    $i = 1;
    while(!$n) {
    $NextLevelXP = pow($i,3) + 2 * $i;
        if($NextLevelXP > $cEXP) {
            $AllLevels = $i;
            break;
        }
    $i++;
    }
}
```

All what I need to know is about optimize possibilities for that, or alternative to get levels amount by `$NextLevelXP = pow($CurrentLevel,3) + 2 * $CurrentLevel;` equation.

Comment: The RPG tag is for the RPG Language.  Please read tag wikis if you do not know what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even do binary search on the value to get **O(logN)** algorithm instead of **O(N)**, but as **N** is the number of levels which I don't think that will be more than 1000, no need to complicate the code. You can do the same you did but with more short code:

```
function getLevels($cEXP) {
    for($i = 1; ($i * $i + 2) * $i <= $cEXP; $i++);
    return $i - 1;
}
```

P.S. Note that I got rid of `pow`, try to avoid it to keep dealing with only integers.